# C# Selenium can't read input value from Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium

I'm using Specflow in Visual Studio to create some Selenium Chrome webdriver tests. My app is in Agular 5

I have an input field in my HTML

```
<input type="text" (change)="onInputChange()" id="{{name}}"  
    [(ngModel)]="inputAddress">
```

I have my test in C#

```
internal bool CheckAddressValue(string address)
        {

            var addressInput = Driver.FindElementById("homePageAddress");

            return addressInput.Text == address;
        }
```

But addressInput.Text is empty, even though there is an address entered. When I inspect the field in Chrome, the address doesn't show up in the source. Any ideas on how I can get the value from the input field?

Comment: what is name in your component?

Comment: homePageAddress

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
var addressInput = Driver.FindElementById("homePageAddress").GetAttribute("value");
```